# Validate currency amounts

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I need to accept values which are valid amounts only. The application supports multiple locales so I need to accept amounts in the following formats:

10.05 or 10,05 (in some locale comma is used for decimal separator)

It should not accept values like 10.456 or 10,456

Users are not allowed to enter symbols like dollar, pound or euro. Also no comma separators allowed (for thousands, millions, billions, etc.). Also, no negatives amounts or zero value amounts are allowed.

Is there a built in .NET method to validate this? It is difficult to use regular expression as I need to allow either comma or dot for decimal separator based on the locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `double.TryParse` function that takes multiple parameters and in particular the [`NumberFormats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) enumeration. If you are specifying the correct culture, it can handle the comma versus decimal issue. I think you'll need tohandle the negative/zero issue separately though.

Comment: Already tried but it returns true if value is 10.456 which is not a valid amount

Comment: I think you're going to need to do this in multiple steps. The TryParse call can handle your culture requirements (Which is the hardest to do on your own). Then you'll need to verify the rest yourself. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Yeah, thats what even I was thinking of doing, but thought let me check on SO if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

- replace , with .
- if position of . in string < than stringlength-2 -> not accepted
- parse to double, if fails -> not accepted

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned not using a RegEx, but it seems like the requirements you have regarding the comma or period are pretty simple.  Wouldn't something like this work?

```
^\d*(\.|,)\d{2}
```

It matches multiple leading digits, checks for either a period OR comma, and then matches only 2 trailing digits.

Comment: Whether comma or period is accepted depends on the user's locale. If as per user's locale he needs to use period but his value contains comma then it needs to be rejected. So this will not work.

Comment: I think the best course of action might be to validate the number format using the culture code, then check the value against the Regex.  The value should pass both tests to be considered 'valid'

Answer (score 1):

Use [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It handles everything you want. You can provide a custom set of [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) as well as a [custom FormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx), if non fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Asp.Net, try the [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). You can set the Type property to currency. If you set the `Operator`  property to `ValidationCompareOperator.DataTypeCheck`, the `CompareValidator`  control ignores both the `ControlToCompare`  and `ValueToCompare`  properties and simply indicates whether the value entered into the input control can be converted to the data type specified by the Type  property.

Comment: This value is send as a HTTP POST from another site so I cannot used CompareValidator. Also my website is using ASP.NET MVC3